# Laravel 5 Eloquent hasMany relationship putting null into key field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an Artist model and an Item model.

```
class Artist extends Model {
    protected $table = 'contactsdata';
    protected $primaryKey = 'c_id';

    public function artworks() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'c_id', 'c_id');
    }
}

class Item extends Model {
    protected $table = 'stock';
    protected $primaryKey = 's_id';
}
```

In my ArtistsController I have this code:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        DB::enableQueryLog();
        $artist = Artist::find($id);
        $artworks = Artist::find($id)->artworks;
        dd(DB::getQueryLog(), $artworks->toArray());        
    }
```

In the database there are many records qualifying to populate $artworks. But this is my dd() output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `contactsdata` where `contactsdata`.`c_id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "2242"
    ]
    "time" => 2.59
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `stock` where `stock`.`c_id` is null"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 2.52
  ]
]
[]
```

For some reason the if field (c_id) is set to null for the second or relationship query. Any ideas? Help!

Comment: Show the tables. And can't you change the schema? Wth is `c_id` `s_id` - it's even hard to read here, not mentioning readability of the code... If that's legacy db, then create some views maybe. One more thing - do you have any accessors in the `Artist` model?

Comment: Yes it is a legacy db and you are right, creating some views would overcome that. As to the rest, see end of thread as I solved it myself - the schema has all its field names in UPPER CASE and Eloquent relationships are CASE SENSITIVE.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Every attribute in Eloquent is case sensitive, for it uses `attributes` array, and array keys are case sensitive. Good you solved it

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you should rather use here:

```
$artist = Artist::find($id);
$artworks = $artist->artworks;
```

instead of:

```
$artist = Artist::find($id);
$artworks = Artist::find($id)->artworks;
```

Comment: No, that makes no difference. The artworks query generated is still "select * from `stock` where `stock`.`c_id` is null". So the id is not getting into the query.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. I have solved this myself. Eloquent relationship field names are case sensitive. For some reason my database table has all its fields (in its scheme) named in UPPER CASE. Once I changed the hasMany parameters to 'C_ID', 'C_ID' everything worked just fine.

So worth knowing that Eloquent relationship field names are CASE SENSITIVE.